# Start ProjectionMedia from a service

Tags: android, android-service, android-windowmanager, android-mediaprojection

I have a floating button being drawing using `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` above all the windows , what am trying to accomplish is once I press on it , I start `ProjectionMedia API` here is what am doing :

```
//passing to it the Main activity
  public MyManager(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        // call for the projection manager
        mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    }

 public void Capture() {
        isWorking = true;
        mHandler = new Handler();
        Intent i = mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent();
       // i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        activity.startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);

    }
```

and in `MainActivity` I have `static MyManager` so I can accesses it from within the service , but once I call `Capture` from the `Service` the app doesn't do anything , and there is nothing in the `logact` , what I'm missing here?

Answer (score -1):

First, you are leaking the memory associated with that activity and everything it references (views, content in those views, etc.).

Second, once the activity is destroyed, you cannot use it anymore, such as for things like `startActivityForResult().`

You need to do the whole `startActivityForResult()` work from your activity before showing your floating window. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaProjection/andcorder), where I use a `Notification` instead of a floating window.